# Shopify embedded app "frame-ancestors 'none'" error

Tags: reactjs, django, shopify, content-security-policy, shopify-app

I am having some issues with my embedded app. I checked the app in incognito mode (chrome) and found that it is not loading any page.

I have configured CSP headers on my django backend with django-csp with middleware (adding screenshot of the API call from XHR section from network tab.

**Tech Stack**

Frontend: React

Backend: Django
Inspection
console prints this error:

> Refused to frame '' because an ancestor violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

I am not able to figure out the issue. I can provide more info if needed.

```py
class CSPMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Check if the request URL matches the desired prefix
        if request.path.startswith('/endpoint'):
            # Apply the CSP header for the desired URL prefix
            response['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors https://shopify-dev.myshopify.com https://admin.shopify.com;"

        return response
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to embed a webpage from `shopify-dev.myshopify.com` in your website.

You are getting the CSP violation error because `shopify-dev.myshopify.com` includes `frame-ancestors 'none'` in its CSP response header. As the [`frame-ancestors` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) is used to specify which webpage may embed the webpage where the directive is used, `frame-ancestors 'none'` effectively prevents any site from embeddding `shopify-dev.myshopify.com`.

Thus, setting the `frame-ancestors` directive on your website will not have any effect on your website's ability to embed pages from `shopify-dev.myshopify.com`.

To solve this problem, you would need to redesign your app to avoid embedding `shopify-dev.myshopify.com`.